# C8051F020 serial communication with GSM module (SIM900)

Tags: microcontroller, uart, serial, gsm, 8051

I am currently trying to interface the GSM900 module with a C8051F020 microcontroller using serial communication in order to send AT commands to the GSM from the 8051.

The TX of the microcontroller is connected to the RX of the GSM module as well as the RX of the microcontroller to the TX of the GSM module. In the Silicon Labs C8051F020 microcontroller example code UART0 is used for serial communication, which makes use of pin 0 and pin 1 on port 0, however, on the development board the port pins are inducated as NC which means Not Connected/No Connect.

Reading the documentation I saw I had to enable the crossbar in order to use UART 1 on pins 2 and 3 on port 0 as TX and RX for serial communication between the microcontroller and the GSM module.

After many tries I can't seem to get it to work with the 8051. I have sent the same AT commands using an Arduino to the GSM module and it responds accordingly, however, I do not get any response when doing so with the 8051.

I think there might be some pin configuration I am missing or possibly a difference in operating voltage/signal between the two which causes the GSM not to receive the AT commands. I was told a logic level converter might be needed as possibly the operating pin voltages of the two are different.

I would appreciate any advice, code example, or resources to solve this issue as I'm not sure where exactly the problem might be.

Comment: Can you temporarily replace the GSM TX and RX by a serial port of an Arduino to test the communication? This way you can distinguish between TX and  RX problems.

Comment: Please use an oscilloscope to watch the wires, and compare Arduino and 8051. -- You could also provide a minimal and compilable example of your 8051 application, with emphasis on "complete" and "minimal".